# passing this to an outer class and starting an activity from alertdialog's list on Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-context

I am developing an Android app, this app has a dozen of Activities, each one is for a corresponding screen. Now I have this common subtitle bar on top of the screens.
this subtitle bar has a button to display an alert dialog which shows link list to go to a different screen.

I could write a same function for each activity to call the alert dialog, but that would be tedious if I want to modify them, so I created this class:

```
public class MenuAlertDialog extends Activity {

/*
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
 */
public void createMenu(final Context context){
    AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dlg.setTitle("menu");

    String[] items = {"pageA", "pageB", "pageC", "pageD", "pageE"};
    dlg.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            switch(which){
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                break;

            }
        }
    });
    dlg.show();
}
}
```

and call it from each activity, like this:

```
MenuAlertDialog menu = new MenuAlertDialog();
menu.createMenu(this);
```

from inside of onCreate.

It can display the alertDialog, but whenever I press pageA link, it fails with an unexpected error.

Logcat says its a nullpointererror and the cause seems

```
startActivity(intent);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
in above code context is null that is the cause.

Comment: Well, not related to your problem but why are you extending your class as an Activity? If what you have posted above is all that's in that class it's completely redundant to extend that class with anything.

Comment: Android_CrazyThank you for your quick response! could you also tell me how can I fix it? please.

Comment: And it is so, because you probably should not inherit from Activity but some Dialog Class.
dymmeh is right - no inheritance is needed at all for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your advice dymmeh I'm new to Java and android so I'm still in the dark for how to program in Java on android. I'll fix it!

Comment: I tried to delete extends Activity, but If I delete "extends Activity" I can not use startActivity... what should I do?

Comment: Glad I made you do that because I found your problem based on what you just posted. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the code

```
extends Activity
```

as you have no need to extend your class that you are creating since it does not rely on any activity related functionality.

Where you call `startActivity(intent);` replace it with

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the class to Extends Dialog and not activity. 
Also for Try this:

Check out this tutorial on how to create a custom dialog. [Custom Dialog](http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/02/create-custom-dialog.html)
Also Here [Another Tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application)
And [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: Also Try removing the Final from  (Final Context context)

Comment: Thank you for your advice coder_For_Life22 but it still gives me error... I tried to change the super class from Activity to Dialog but if I do that startActivity won't work...

Comment: Check out my edit. Ive posted full tutorials that will fix your issue, and put you on the correct path to creating the dialog you need above.

Comment: Great They are good tutorials and will definitely fix your problem and have you on your way.